# cassandra-cli alternative to see how data is stored

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to wrap my brain around cassandras datamodel. Therefore I would like to use cassandra-cli but it is not install in the official docker container.

This tool is also deprecated or not used anymore. Is there any alternative vay to see how the data is stored.

I do use cqlsh, but I need to see how data is laid out to understand insert etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download the CLI binary from any other Cassandra installation and use it with the Cassandra installation in your Docker container.